# ¿Cómo puedo pasar este DispatcherTimer a una función o clase?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

tengo una duda.
¿cómo puedo pasar este DispatcherTimer a una función o clase separada para poner reutilizarla?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1) };
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
    tbxHora.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
}
```

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbxHora.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
}
```

Comment: Podrías especificar un poco mas que es lo que necesitas

Comment: Y así como lo entiendo ahorita, te pueden servir los [Delegates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-declare-instantiate-and-use-a-delegate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que mover la logica al constructor de la clase y exponer los metodos que necesites para detener o notificar con cada ticks:

```
public class Ticker
{
  public event EventHandler<DateTime> OnTick;
  DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
  public Ticker(int segundos = 1)
  {
     this.dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(segundos) };
     this.dispatcherTimer.Tick += (evt, args)=> this.OnTick?.Invoke(this, DateTime.Now);
     this.dispatcherTimer.Start();
  }

  public Action Stop = () => this.dispatcherTimer.Stop();

}
```

Uso:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var ticks = new Ticks();
    ticks.OnTick = Timer_Tick;
}

private void Timer_Tick(DateTime time)
{
    tbxHora.Content = time.ToString("G");
}
```